# Deleting of files from isolated storage isn't working.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

The directory have been mapped as indicated in the LoadFiles Method. However, the Delete code isn't able to delete the files from the directory in the isolated storage, even though it has already been mapped.

Here is the LoadFile method:

```
 private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files
        {
            get
            {
                this._files = this._files ?? this.LoadFiles();
                return this._files;
            }
        }


        private ObservableCollection<FileItem> LoadFiles()
        {
            ObservableCollection<FileItem> files = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();


            foreach (string filePath in this.Store.GetFileNames("FlashCardApp\\"))
                files.Add(new FileItem { FileName = filePath });
            return files;
        }
```

Here's the delete code that it's suppose to delete the files from the directory after it is checked, but it is unable to do so even if the store.FileExist has already been mapped to the LoadFiles method:

```
  private void OnDeleteSelected()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            List<FileItem> removedItems = new List<FileItem>();
            foreach (var item in Files)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked)
                    if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
                    {
                        storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
                        removedItems.Add(item);
                    }
            }

            foreach (var item in removedItems)
                Files.Remove(item);
        }
```

EDIT:

Here is the Isolated Storage Class:

```
  private IsolatedStorageFile currentStore;
        public IsolatedStorageFile Store
        {
            get
            {
                this.currentStore = this.currentStore ?? IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                return this.currentStore;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code snippet you are using this.Store to access the IsolatedStorage, and in the second you are referring to IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); do these both point to the same location?

Also, in the second code snippet, does the storage.FileExists(item.FileName) return true? or do you need to append "FlashCardApp\" to the filename? For example: `storage.FileExists("FlashCardApp\\" + item.FileName);`

Comment: i've edit my question, adding the isolated Storage class. And yes, they seem to point to the same location. About the second question, i'm not sure whetehr it returns true, and i do not know how to append "FlashCardApp\\" to the FileName.

Comment: It should return true, since it's `if(something happen){then something else happen}`

Comment: And this is a project that i'm using the visual basic studio 2010 to do, please do not remove the tag.

Comment: @fatty- thanks mate, never knew it was this easy! took me 2 days trying to solve this problem!

Comment: another thing I have just noticed - does the files collection actually contain any items when you omit the wildcard character from `this.Store.GetFileNames("FlashCardApp\\*")` ?

Comment: that's the reason why I've added `"FlashCardApp\\"` in `this.Store.GetFileNames()`. If i didn't add, it won't find the file, as i didn't map it........ took me 1 whole day to solve this problem as well........... I dunno how it works and all, but after trying to add that into `this.Store.GetFileNames()`, i've gotten the result that i wanted.

Comment: @fatty- and that's the reason why

Comment: Just small addon: probably you wish to use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)